# Custom list edit item access, no code

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a custom list and i need to apply some edit restriction to this. There is status field on the form that will be changed by users.

- When user selects "Draft" in status field and saves then this item
  will only be edited by user who is saving it.
- When user1 selects "sent" in the status field and saves then this
  item will only be editable by user whose name is selected in
  "Approver" field.
- When user, whose name is selected in "Approver" field selects
  "Rejected" and saves then this item will only be editable by user who
  created it(user from point 1, 2).
- When user, whose name is selected in "Approver" field selects
  "Approved" and saves then this item will only be editable by nobody.

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that at 1st glance this could be the case for a SharePoint 2010 Designer workflow that changes Security on that Item upon field change. Use the "Wait for field change" activity in the SPD 2010 to monitor changes on the Status field and update security accordingly.

I do not normally prefer fiddling with breaking security inheritance but is seems that in this specific case, one solution would be to do it as such. at least try using SharePoint Groups with Permission level to easier control groups of users and not individuals

Comment: Thanks Marius, I have created groups in order to allow users to be able to see specific view, for example I have created a group for approvers and only member of this group can see the link of sharepoint view "Pending approve" which shows items with field status = "sent". But here problem is any member from approvers view can edit items in this view. That is why I want to go with item level security, could you please provide some info how can I set edit access by updating security using sharepoint designer workflow. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Have you already considered http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/ ?